# iOS: Does disabling Safari restrict all web browsers?

Tags: ios

If Safari is disabled under restrictions in the settings app, will that prevent the launch of third party browsers as well, or is it pointless without also disabling the App Store app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not restrict other browsers, you would have to set controls on the app store to prevent the download of 3rd party browsers.